# Why "my,string".Split(',') works in .NET C#

Tags: c#, .net, split

Why `"my,string".Split(',')` works in .NET C# ?

The declaration of Split according to MSDN is `Split(Char[])`.
[MSDN String.Split Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.String.Split.aspx)

I supposed that C# 5 converts the single char `','` to `char[] {','}`;
But I must be wrong because the following code doesn't work:

```
static void Main()
{
    GetChar(',');
}

static char GetChar(char[] input)
{
    return input[0];
}
```

EDIT: Thanks to the Jon Skeet's answer I changed the argument to `params char[]` and it works proving the concept.

```
static char GetChar(params char[] input)
{
    return input[0];
}
```

Comment: Note the `params` keyword on the `Split` method's prototype, which indicates that the method can take a variable number of `char` parameters that will be combined into a single array.

Comment: In C#, when you use single quotes around a single character is is interpreted as a char (not char[]).  Double quotes denotes a string.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The [overload you're using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx) uses a [*parameter array*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx), basically. That's what the `params` part is. The compiler automatically wraps up your single argument into an array. So this:

```
var x = text.Split(',');
```

is equivalent to:

```
var x = text.Split(new char[] { ',' });
```

You can use a parameter array for your own methods too, with the `params` keyword:

```
static char GetChar(params char[] input)
{
    return input[0];
}
```

Note that the parameter array has to be the *final* parameter. That is why the overload you're using is the *only* overload of `Split` to use a parameter array. Look at the other overloads:

```
Split(Char[], Int32)
Split(Char[], StringSplitOptions)
Split(String[], StringSplitOptions)
Split(Char[], Int32, StringSplitOptions)
Split(String[], Int32, StringSplitOptions)
```

In each of these cases, the array is the *first* parameter, so you have to construct an array yourself:

```
var x = text.Split(new char[] { ',' }, 10); // Call the (char[], int) overload
```

Or using an implicitly-typed array:

```
var x = text.Split(new[] { ',' }, 10); // Call the (char[], int) overload
```

Answer (score 5):

The actual overload that's being called is [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx). Note that the header at the top of the page is misleading, it actually takes `params char[]` instead of `char[]`. This allows you to pass in separators as `"my, string".Split(',', ' ')` instead of making you jump through the hoop of using `"my, string".Split(new char[] { ',', ' ' })` first.